# TweetSharp - how to get friends list?

Tags: c#, twitter, oauth, tweetsharp

How do I get the user's friend list using tweet sharp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an alternative solution, I don't know how to do it with tweet sharp, but you can make a call to:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=yourusername
```

Then you get a json file with the ids.

To get the info of your followers, you can use:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?user_id=123456789&include_entities=true
```

(With 123456789 being the id of the follower)

More info:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/followers/ids

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/lookup